# In sql, can you join to a select statement that references the outer tables in other joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

What I want to do is to transform the following sql

```
SELECT X 
FROM Y LEFT JOIN Z ON Y.Id=Z.id
WHERE Y.Fld='P'
```

into

```
SELECT Y 
FROM Y LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Z WHERE Z.Id=Y.Id ORDER BY Z.PrimaryKey DESC) ON 1=1
WHERE Y.Fld='P'
```

The reason I want to do this is because Z has multiple rows that can be joined to Y, that are not unique  in a distinguishable way, other than that the one we need is the latest one, and we only need that one record. Is this possible? I tried it but mssql complained that I cannot reference Y.Id from within the sub query.

Comment: Change the `Left Join` to an `Outer Apply` and remove the `ON 1 = 1`

Comment: You should do exactly what @Siyual said, but with the only caveat that you need to add an alias to it: `SELECT X FROM Y OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP.....) B .....`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The order by makes not sense to me as you are not reporting anything from Z.

Comment: This was just a simplified example, sorry it wasnt complete. the real query i am working with is much much larger, but I isolated the section I had a question about

Answer (score 1):

How about a CTE approach:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Id, 
           PrimaryKey, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, ORDER BY Primarykey Desc) AS RN
    FROM Z
)
SELECT X
FROM Y
LEFT JOIN CTE
   ON CTE.ID = Y.ID
WHERE CTE.RN = 1
```